# Constrained eager load not performing the additional query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to load a collection of Species, sorted by the 'name' column of their Genus, and then sorted by their own 'name' column.

```
$webstore_species = Species::where('in_webstore', true)
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->with(['genus' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
    }])->get();
```

But the $query is never executed and the results are only sorted on the Species name. If I change it from orderBy to say another where function for testing, it doesn't get executed either.

But as far as I can tell the `'genus'` relation is correct and working fine and I seem to be following the documentation on Eager Loading for this.

```
class Species extends Model
{
    /** Return the many-to-one relationship with the Genus model.
     * 
     * @return App\Models\Genus
     */
    public function genus()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Genus::class);
    }
}
```

That the relationship works is shown when I do the following in Tinker:

```
>>> $species = Species::find(46)
=> App\Models\Species {#3201
     id: 46,
     name: "vagus",
     genus_id: 2,
     in_webstore: 1,
     slug: "camponotus-vagus",
     created_at: "2018-09-30 07:10:26",
     updated_at: "2019-08-18 21:45:00",
   }
>>> $species->genus
=> App\Models\Genus {#3172rBy('name', 'asc');
     id: 2,
     name: "Camponotus",
   }
```

By the way, I don't know what `#3172rBy('name', 'asc')` here comes from and if it has any bearing on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the `Genus` model should be easier, seen that you want to start ordering with Genus name and because it has a one to many relationship with `Species`, you can try with this query:

```php
$webstore_genuses = Genus::orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->with(['species' => function($query) {
        $query->where('in_webstore', true)->orderBy('name', 'asc');
    }])->get();
```

But I don't know if you can deal with the result in your view, it should not be difficult.

BTW with your query you are asking laravel to get all `Species` orderded by name and for each species load the `Genus` ordered by name, but a `Species` have only one `Genus` so the ordering make no sense.

**Update**: probably the better way is to use a `join` so you can order on `Genus` name and `Species` name in the same query you use to retrieve `Species`, something like this:

```php
$webstore_species = Species::->with('genus')
    ->where('in_webstore', true)
    ->join('genuses', 'genuses.id', '=', 'species.genus_id')
    ->orderBy('genuses.name', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('species.name', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: @stroomschok any feeedback on this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what dparoli said. Using ...

```
->with(['genus' => function($query) {
   $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}])
```

... you are applying order by name within each species Genuses, which is always one, so that basically does nothing.

You should apply order using dot notation:

```php
$webstore_species = Species::with('genus')
   ->where('in_webstore', true)   
   ->orderBy('genus.name', 'asc')
   ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
   ->get();
```